call failed with status BadNotImplemented (eclipse milo)
I've tried to add namespaces to the example server, like as been done in
https://github.com/kevinherron/machine-example/tree/master, 
(just changed some xml file).
I start the server and when I connect with UaExpert I see what I'm expecting to view, and that is good:

But when I call I method like GetLatestResult i get:

I'm new to EclipseMilo and OpcUA, I've tried to google on the error, try to figure out how I can implemement that node but no success at all.
For example
try to get the node:
NodeId methodId = NodeId.parse("ns=2;s=GetLatestResult");
and do something with it methodId.invoke()......
but on methodId I didnt see any method that can be useful for implement it!!!
I do not know even if is that possible.

I solved this issue as indicated in
https://github.com/eclipse/milo/discussions/1276
Anyway I post here the solution here in order to avoid the error "call failed with status BadNotImplemented"
//trovo il nodo 
    NodeId objectId8 = NodeId.parse("ns=8;i=72");
    Optional<UaNode> on = server.getAddressSpaceManager().getManagedNode(objectId8);
    
    UaObjectNode myObject1 = (UaObjectNode) on.get();
    List<UaMethodNode> listMethod = myObject1.getMethodNodes();
     
    listMethod.forEach((n) -> System.out.println(n.getBrowseName()));
    
    //trovo il metodo  
    NodeId method = NodeId.parse("ns=8;i=97");
    Optional<UaNode> on1 = server.getAddressSpaceManager().getManagedNode(method);
     UaMethodNode methodNode = (UaMethodNode) on1.get();
     
     AbortJoiningProcess aJp = new AbortJoiningProcess(methodNode);
     listMethod.get(0).setInvocationHandler(aJp);

Now the error is different but is another issue;
